# Spring upload multiple file how to identify each file?

Tags: java, spring, web

I want to upload multiple files. And I need to identify each file in the backend. I want to use the name in the dom element, but if I give every input a different name, my spring controller will not get the multiple files.The files of my form is not fixed. I also have to render different files input by user's change. So The controller part must not be fixed style, need to be a array.

```
<input type="file" name="files" />
<input type="file" name="files" />


@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files
```

I have searched but not found some help. My only solution is to pass some extra information to the backend to identify each file. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe it would help if you explained why you need to use two input tags, like explaining a bit what your page is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `MultipartFile#getOriginalFilename()` to get the file name.

```
<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file1"/>
    <input type="file" name="file2"/>
    <input type="file" name="file3"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

(@RequestParam(value = "file1") MultipartFile file1,
 @RequestParam(value = "file2") MultipartFile file2,
 @RequestParam(value = "file3") MultipartFile file3)
```

what about this way?

Comment: sorry, I can not depends on the file name to identify the file type

Comment: what about the other way?

Comment: not work.The files of my form is not fixed. I also have to render different files input by user's change. So The controller part must not be fixed style, need to be a array.

Answer (score 0):

The multiparts from the MultipartFile[] files array is the same one as the order of the file inputs from the frontend. You can use this to match them.

For example if I have in the frontend:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/test" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files" /> <!-- this will be multipartFiles[0] -->
    <input type="file" name="files" /> <!-- this will be multipartFiles[1] -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

In the controller if I have something like :

```
@PostMapping("/test")
@ResponseBody
public List<String> fileSubmit(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] multipartFiles){

    List<String> fileNames = Arrays
            .stream(multipartFiles)
            .map(MultipartFile::getOriginalFilename)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return fileNames;
}
```

Then I can identify the files I sent based on their order in the html form which will match the multipartFiles array index.
[Here](https://github.com/gozman1989/SpringMVCMultipartArray) is an example for you to paly with.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I think it should work. It is very helpful.